# Convert dataframe column into set of text files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains `topic` and `keywords` column as shown below:

```
topic   keyword
    0   ['player', 'team', 'word_finder_unscrambler', ...
    1   ['weather', 'forecast', 'sale', 'philadelphia'...
    2   ['name', 'state', 'park', 'health', 'dog', 'ce...
    3   ['game', 'flight', 'play', 'game_live', 'play_...
    4   ['dictionary', 'clue', 'san_diego', 'professor...
```

Need to create a text file of each topic separately namely topic1.txt, topic2.txt,....topic20.txt and the topic text file should contain strings in newline inside keyword column something like this:

```
topic1.txt file should contain:

player
team
word_finder_unscrambler
etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each row of `DataFrame` create new txt file by name with `topic` column with add `1`:

```
import csv

for t, k in zip(df['topic'], df['keyword']):
    with open(f"topic{t + 1}.txt","w") as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\n")
        wr.writerow(k)
```

EDIT: Because no lists but strings in `keyword` column use:

```
import csv, ast

for t, k in zip(df['topic'], df['keyword']):
    with open(f"topic{t + 1}.txt","w") as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\n")
        wr.writerow(ast.literal_eval(k))
```

Comment: Since topics are list inside the column so above bit of code of yours is giving output as ```[
'
p
l
a
y
e
r
'
,
 
'
t
e
a
m
'
```